# Excel increment cellsand skip weekends or holidays

Tags: excel, regex, google-sheets, excel-formula

I had a google sheet that I am trying to translate to an excel file.  The original formula is this:

```
=Arrayformula(if(J2:J<>"", regexreplace(J2:J, "[^A-Z]",), if( (weekday(B2:B) = 1)+(weekday(B2:B) = 7), ,countifs (weekday(B2:B), ">1", weekday(B2:B), "<7", J2:J, "", row(B2:B), "<="&row(B2:B)))))
```

I am looking to convert this to something in excel.  Basically the idea behind this formula was that it would count down a column (A) looking at the next column (B) to see what the date was.  If it was a weekend, it would skip the increment.  If it was a work day, it would increment.  This allowed me to automatically count down 20 work days for a sprint.  Then it would look at a 2nd column (J) for any Notes in that column.  If anything was in the column, it would skip that increment and put a letter in that row (column A).  For example, if I put "Holiday" in column J, it would be an "H" in that row in column A.  That way I could still count down to plan out 20 work days easily.

It worked fine in Google Sheets, but the translation to Excel was not as easy as I would have hoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WEEKDAY`.

For example, based on your description you could try:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(G2)=1, WEEKDAY(G2)=7), "",
IF(ISBLANK(H2)=FALSE, H2,
MAX(F$1:F1)+1))
```

[image]

EDIT as suggested by @Marti:
A much cleaner way is to use a second argument in the `WEEKDAY` function, and then cut down on the number of characters in the second `IF`.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(G2, 3)>=5, "", 
IF(ISBLANK(H2), MAX(F$1:F1)+1, H2))
```

Comment: Nice answer! I would improve it a bit: `=IF(WEEKDAY(G2, 3)>=5, "", IF(ISBLANK(H2), MAX(F$1:F1)+1, H2))`